# Problem deserializing Google profile response

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, google-oauth, xamarin.auth

I'm authenticating to google in a `Xamarin.Forms` app. Once authenticated I want to retrieve user email, and use this code that I adapted from [this blog](http://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/), the code for retrieving the email:

```
public class GoogleProfile
{
    [Preserve]
    [JsonConstructor]
    public GoogleProfile() { }

    public string sub { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string given_name { get; set; }
    public string profile { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string email_verified { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
}

public class GoogleService
{
    public async Task<string> GetEmailAsync(string tokenType, string accessToken)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tokenType, accessToken);
        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo");//https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email?alt=json");
        var profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleProfile>(json);
        return profile.email;
    }
}
```

Now, with a breakpoint in the last line `return profile.email` I've "seen" the json file that is this way:

```
{
  "sub": "",
  "name": "",
  "given_name": "",
  "profile": "",
  "picture": "",
  "email": "",
  "email_verified": "",
  "locale": "",
}
```

Between the quotes are the data, obviously.

I'm not really accustomed to JSon but reading [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) I thought that the format is simply `"nameOfProperty":"ValueOfProperty"`, so I made `GoogleProfile` object.

I read too that the attributes `[Preserve]` and `[JsonConstructor]` are necessary so the linker doesn't just "remove" empty constructors when compiling.

There are no exceptions and no apparent problems, but if I put a breakpoint in the last `return profile.email;` line, I can see the `json` object has all the data and is perfectly fine, but the `profile` object have **only** the `email` property with value `null`...

I don't understand it: what happened with the other properties? Is it even possible? You know, you code an object with a bunch of properties but the object are created with only one of those properties? If the object had all the properties with a value of null, Ok, but where did the other properties gone?

Just to be sure, I've cleaned and rebuild projects and solution, I've removed `bin` and `obj` folders and then clean and rebuild again... I've done the obvious things.

Thing is that as you can see in the blog I mentioned earlier, first I didn't use `GoogleProfile` object, I just copied the object in the blog... that has only one property called `email`. Is it possible that visual studio or xamarin or something got bugged and the changes didn't got reflected? I doubt it because I've changed the URI used in the `GetStringAsync` method and it did got reflected, but well, I don't know.

PD: In the meanwhile I'm parsing the JSON directly as a normal string, it's a simple object and I only really need the email, but well, it would be a shame that I'd have to parse it that way instead of just deserialize it.

---

**Edit:**
As suggested by Skin in the comments I've used http://jsonutils.com/

One of the properties was a bool (of course), so I've changed it and the object now is:

```
public class GoogleProfile
{
    [Preserve]
    [JsonConstructor]
    public GoogleProfile() { }

    public string sub { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string given_name { get; set; }
    public string profile { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool email_verified { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
}
```

But it didn't change the result, still happening the same. Image of the result at the breakpoint:

[image: Breakpoint values]

Comment: ??? So the example POCO GoogleProfile doesn't have all of the other properties returned by the API call? Why would you need to parse the JSON string?? JSONConvert.Deserialize<T> should do the work for you and place all the property values inside of your POCO class object. Have you set a break point at `var profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleProfile>(json);` and checke d the value of variable `json` ? Does it have an email address? If not it will get set to null.

Comment: Yes, as I say in the question. With a breakpoint I check the value of variable `json` and is exactly as the sample I wrote in the question but with the correct values between the quotes... then I do the json deserializing and the object `profile` get created only with one property called `email` with value null.

Comment: Have you tried adding in the rest of the properties so that it can deserialize all of them? Maybe give that a try.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand "addint in the rest of the properties". All the properties are coded in the object, and all the values in the json retrieved . I'm an amateur and I have not used that much JSON, maybe you are referring to something I don't know. I just thought if the text file has a tag that matches the object property name, the deserializer would apply the values to the correct properties without further coding.

Comment: Grab your json, go to jsonutils.com and let it create the class for you.

Comment: @Skin Did it. It changes a bit the object but not the result. I updated the question.

Comment: @Nox without providing any sensitive data, can you actually provide the json string for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any problem with your code. I used the same code of you and didn't change anything. I use my own `tokenType` and `accessToken`.

My steps:

1. copy your code to my project.
2. get my own token by using the project in the [blog](http://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/)
3. install `newtonsoft` Nuget package
4. run the project and get result

So, is there any problem with your account? Did you account have an e-mail? Any difference with mine?

Here is what I get:

[image: json Result]

**Code:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        testAsync();
    }

    public async Task testAsync()
    {

        GoogleService googleS = new GoogleService();
        // use your token here
        var email = await googleS.GetEmailAsync("", "");
        Console.WriteLine(email);
    }

    public class GoogleProfile
    {
        [Preserve]
        [JsonConstructor]
        public GoogleProfile() { }

        public string sub { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string given_name { get; set; }
        public string profile { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string email_verified { get; set; }
        public string locale { get; set; }
    }

    public class GoogleService
    {
        public async Task<string> GetEmailAsync(string tokenType, string accessToken)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo");//https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email?alt=json");
            var profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleProfile>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(json);
            Console.WriteLine(profile);


            return profile.email;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My code is the same as yours, the json has all the data including the email. I'm afraid the real problem is related to this one: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45327/newest-version-of-code-not-always-deployed-when-debugging-from-xamarin-studio

Comment: Basically not all changes doesn't get reflected when deploying. Before all this I had a different object, I suspect that someway the app are being compiled with the new code on `GoogleService` but the old code in `GoogleProfile`, so JSON can't deserialize it correctly therefore no email for me. I'll try to see if that solves the problem and update the question

Comment: You can try delete bin and obj folder, then rebuild the project.

Comment: You can also create a new project to check the problem.

Comment: Now it works... for a moment I thought I couldn't do it. I tried deleting folders and all, but for me only worked to deactivate fast deployment and to change linker to only SDK assemblies, in the android project properties. But well, it works now. I'll accept your answer since it confirmed me that the problem wasn't the code and guided me to the real problem.